# How to exit from function that calls thread but keep thread going?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have been working on some C project where I have a function that calls `pthread_create()` but I need that function to return and to keep the threaded function going.

Here's my code:

```
audio_file
play(char file_name[])
{
    /* Plays audio file  */

    pthread_t thread; 


    audio_file a_file = p_get_file(file_name);

    if(a_file.type != BROKEN)
        pthread_create(&thread,NULL,audio_output,&a_file);

    return a_file;
}
```

Comment: Besides the obvious missing `pthread_detach`, was there a specific problem you were having? I.e. does this *not* do what you're asking (especially once you fix it by detaching the thread) ? I see one glaring issue. Your thread is receiving `a_file` by address, which means upon exit of this function that address is no longer valid and you're thread has a dangling pointer. You prolly wanna fix that pronto.

Comment: I did not know about that pointer thing, will fix it.There were no problems otherwise, i just want to return a_file and continue with the code while the func audio_output works in the background i tried passing pthread_t but thread stops after i exit play().

Comment: Can't really offer a definitive solution because I have no idea what an `audio_file` even is. Chance are its a pointer to something already, and is abstracted in whatever toolkit you're using as a "handle" thing. Do some investigating. What you have now has a clear problem with lifetime of `a_file` since you're giving it to the thread proc by address. Once that function returns, there is no `a_file` variable anymore, and the thread function is left accessing lord-knows-what.

Comment: Why don't you use the function `fork()`?

Comment: The thread should keep going in the code as shown.  Perhaps the problem is that you are allowing the process's main thread to `exit()` or return from `main()` before the spawned thread has completed its execution?  Doing either of those will prematurely halt any other running threads; the standard way to deal with that is to have the main thread call `pthread_join()` on any spawned threads before the main thread exits, so that the main thread will wait until all of the spawned threads have exited, before exiting itself.

Answer (score 0):

You do pthread_detach in the thread that should keep going. If that thread was created from the main thread, main thread should exit with pthread_exit instead of exit().